# mysql php where clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Any ideas why this wouldnt work!?

Just nothing displays..

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from `suppliers` where supp_short_code='WED'") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                    {       
                        echo "<p>" . $row1['supp_name'] . "</p>";
                    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the output from mysql_error() so that we can see the error that is being raised.

Comment: We need more information, please show us your connection, and also a sample from your database structure as well as a few rows that can validate the data required is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved! turns out when i imported from Excel to my mysql in brought in spaces after and before the "supp_short_code" so the query wasnt working!

Comment: You can use MySQL `TRIM()` function for this, for example `INSERT INTO myTabe (number, string) VALUES (12, TRIM("    something    "))` - it will store the string without whitespaces before and after first/last characters.

Answer (score 1):

Is 'supp_name' a column of your 'suppliers' table?

Does this query return any result under phpmyadmin eg?

Are the `<p>` tags displayed (no rules as `display:none;`)?

Comment: Weirdly this works SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supp_short_code LIKE '%WED%' but not "=WED" i can see the supp_short_code is definitely WED, unless its counting spaces because there might be a space after "WED " in the db!?

Comment: @user478144: that means that the exact string 'WED' is not stored in your table. You likely have some space characters. Try the query with `TRIM(supp_short_code)='WED'` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your connection?  If there isn't one, `mysql_query()` tries to make one by calling `mysql_connect()` with no args. It also fails if your connection doesn't have permissions for the table you're trying to read.  If it's not dying but only returning no result, then check `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

correct quotes of this line :: 
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from suppliers where supp_short_code='WED'") or die(mysql_error());